# Declaring variables inside functions in solidity not working

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I have the following code in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract testcontract {
    function testme () returns (string){
        string mystring = "foo2";
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

And I get the following **TypeError**:

```
browser/dummy2.sol:5:9: TypeError: Type literal_string "foo2" is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.
    string mystring = "foo2";
    ^----------------------^
```

If I just do `string mystring;`, I don't get the error, and as the **TypeError** describes, there is an issue with the assigning of the "foo2" value to the `string mystring`, but I can't figure out why this is happening. Does this mean that variables can't be declared and initiated inside functions? I don't have the issue when it's outside of the function and within the contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix, you need to set `mystring` in `memory` since `storage` is the default.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract testcontract {
    function testme () returns (string){
        string memory mystring = "foo2";
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

If you set a `string` within a function, since the default is `storage`, it will look for you to set that `memory` string as the pointer of the `storage` string...and not a string literal.

Example:

```
contract testcontract {
    string mystringStorage = "Blah";

    function testme () returns (string){
        // String Literal Set In Memory
        string memory mystring = "foo2";

        // String Set From a Pointer
        string mystringMemory = mystringStorage;

        return "foo";
    }
}
```